# How do I make a DetailsView CheckBoxField visible in edit mode in IE6?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6, detailsview

```
<%-- In IE6, in edit mode, the checkbox isn't visible --%>
<asp:DetailsView ID="MyDetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%"
        AutoGenerateRows="False" SkinID="detailsViewSkin" DataKeyNames="SerialNumber"
        DataSourceID="DetailsObjectDataSource">
   <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's really standing out here is that you're missing the **Fields** tag in your gridview.  Other than that, nothing looks out of the ordinary - and I use DetailsViews all the time with no big problems in IE6.

```
<%-- In IE6, in edit mode, the checkbox isn't visible --%>
<asp:DetailsView ID="MyDetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="100%" AutoGenerateRows="False" SkinID="detailsViewSkin" DataKeyNames="SerialNumber" DataSourceID="DetailsObjectDataSource">
   <Fields>
      <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
   </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

I just had a need for this again, so retested in IE6, and my CheckBoxFields work fine.  I'm wondering if there is something in CSS or your skin file that is interfering with IE6.